# Identifying shared polygon boundaries in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, adjacency

I am aware you can dissolve boundaries (standard feature analysis tool) but is there a way you can calculate polygons that share a boundary?

I have attached picture with an example of the polygon data I have.

[image: Attached a picture of the polygon data I have, Is there a way of identifying the polygons that share a boundary?]

Comment: You mean like by using [Polyon To Line](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/polygon-to-line.htm)?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate"?

Comment: Calculate - as in can I get the number (the amount) of individual polygons that are joined together in each block

Comment: almost like a count function ?

Answer (score 2):

To do this I would use the [Polygon Neighbors](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/polygon-neighbors.htm) tool which (with my bolding):

> Creates a table with statistics based on polygon contiguity (overlaps,
> **coincident edges**, or nodes).

Comment: This will include polygons that share single vertex. Polygon to line creates shared boundaries with parents fids. Outer lines have left fid = -1.

Comment: @FelixIP Node neighbors and edge neighbors can be distinguished by field values in the output.

Answer (score 1):

For example [Intersect](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/how-intersect-analysis-works.htm) with

> Polygon inputs and line output:

[image]

Then you can Select By Location to select the polygons that intersect the intersect lines.

Comment: Can this tool be used in Arcpro ??